# FFMPEG is not working in app service post deployment

Tags: .net, ffmpeg, azure-web-app-service

I using the Xabe.FFmpeg package to generate clips from a video. The code is basically converting a video to multiple clips and it's working fine in my local but whenever I am uploading the code to app service the code is not working.

Stack: .net
App Service OS : Windows

Error:

2024-02-13 08:57:34.092 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer: Connection ID "16573246629528734243", Request ID "40000a24-0000-e600-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (193): An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\Controllers\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe' with working directory 'C:\home\site\wwwroot'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()at Xabe.FFmpeg.FFmpeg.RunProcess(String args, String processPath, Nullable`1 priority, Boolean standardInput, Boolean standardOutput, Boolean standardError)at Xabe.FFmpeg.FFmpegWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<RunProcess>b__0()at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__281_0(Object obj)at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)--- End of stack trace from previous location ---at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)--- End of stack trace from previous location ---at Xabe.FFmpeg.Conversion.Start(String parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at ExtractResponseAPI.Controllers.HomeController.PrepareVideoClips(CloudBlockBlob sourceVideoBlob, TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime) in C:\Users\tushar.h.gupta\source\repos\ExtractResponseAPI\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 164at ExtractResponseAPI.Controllers.HomeController.GetIntervalsAsync(String query) in C:\Users\tushar.h.gupta\source\repos\ExtractResponseAPI\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 60at ExtractResponseAPI.Controllers.HomeController.Get(String query) in C:\Users\tushar.h.gupta\source\repos\ExtractResponseAPI\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 24at lambda_method4(Closure, Object)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()

Code:

```
private async Task<List<string>> PrepareVideoClips(CloudBlockBlob sourceVideoBlob, TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime)
{
    string tempDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    // Create a temporary directory to store clips locally
    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectory);

    // Download the source video
    string sourceVideoPath = Path.Combine(tempDirectory, "sourceVideo.mp4");
    await sourceVideoBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(sourceVideoPath, FileMode.Create);
    FFmpeg.SetExecutablesPath("Controllers\\ffmpeg\\bin\\");
    // Use FFmpegCore to trim the video
    string outputVideoPath = Path.Combine(tempDirectory, "output.mp4");

    await FFmpeg.Conversions.New()
        .AddParameter($"-ss {startTime.TotalSeconds}") // Start time
        .AddParameter($"-i {sourceVideoPath}")
        .AddParameter($"-to {(endTime - startTime).TotalSeconds}") // Duration
        .SetOutput(outputVideoPath)
        .Start();

    // Return a list of file paths for the clips
    return new List<string> { outputVideoPath };
}
```

I tried deploying the app service using different OS but still facing the same issue, I also tried using different packages but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (193): An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\Controllers\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe' with working directory 'C:\home\site\wwwroot'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

The issue is with the path to the FFmpeg executables on Azure App Service. The error message indicates that the application is unable to find the FFmpeg executables in the specified path `/app/wwwroot/ffmpeg`.

In the given code from above question:

> 

```
string sourceVideoPath = Path.Combine(tempDirectory, "sourceVideo.mp4");
await sourceVideoBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(sourceVideoPath, FileMode.Create);
FFmpeg.SetExecutablesPath("Controllers\\ffmpeg\\bin\\");
```

It seems that using `SetExecutablesPath` with a relative path might not be the most reliable approach, especially in the Azure App Service environment where paths can be managed differently.

- Instead, you can upload the FFmpeg executables along with the application and reference them using a relative path or by specifying the absolute path within the application.

Use the below path:

```cs
// Assuming the ffmpeg directory is located in the root directory of your application
string ffmpegDirectory = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ffmpeg", "bin");

// Specify the path to the FFmpeg executables
FFmpeg.SetExecutablesPath(ffmpegDirectory);
```

- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` gives you the base directory of your application, and you concatenate the path to the FFmpeg executables within the `ffmpeg` directory.

**.csproj file:**

```xml
<Project Sck="Microsoft .NET.Sdk.WebjMicrosoft .NET.Sdk .Publish">
<PropertyGroup>
<Output Type>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFrameorkonetcoreapp2.@</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>winl@-x64</RuntimeTdentifiers>

</PropertyGroup>
<ItenGroup>
<PackageReference
<PackageReference 1.6.19" />
<PackageReference fangFire.SqlServer" Version="1.6.19" />
<PackageReference Microsoft AsplletCore.All” Version="2.0.7" />
<PackageReference Microsoft ApplicationInsights.AsplietCore" Versions"
<PackageReference Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver” Version

insole” Version:

“<Packagenererence
<7TEemGroup>
‘itenGroup>

<ProjectReference
TEEROTOOD
TeenGroup>
<llone Updates"Assets\-Fnpeg.exe">
<CopyToOutputDirectory Alway3</ Copy TeOutputDirectory>
<itione>
‘llone Updates"Assets\$fprobe.exe">
<CopyToOutputDirectory »Always</CopyTeOutputDirectory>
<itione>
<llone Updeten"Assets unknown png">
<CopyToOutputDirectory >AlNay'3</CopyTeOutputDirectory>
<itione>
‘lone Updete="Fémpeg.exe">
<CopyToOutputDirectory »Always</CopyTeOutputDirectory>
<itione>
‘lone Usdate="F¥probe.exe">
<CopyToOutputDirectory »Always</CopyTeOutputDirectory>
Briones]
/ TtenGroup>
</POTECE
```

**Executed:**
[image]